# best way to save a datagridview in a database

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, datagridview, export

I have a `datagridview` and a SQLite Database. The datagrid can have ANY number of rows and Any number of columns.

i need to save this datagrid to the SQLite database, in order to be able to repopulate it exactly the same way in a second moment. I know how to create tables, populate tables etc, so this is not a question on how to do it. what i would need to know is what the BEST way to do it is. it has to be fast and reliable andmust be possible to update.

Any sugestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends a little on how you fill your DataGridView.

1. If you use the DataSource and a list of objects, you can store the properities in your database. The capital letters "ANY" looks for me, that this is not your solution, but i added it to be complete.
2. If you fill the grid direct (items.add), you can store the values as name-value pairs in the database
3. If you fill the grid direct and dislike (2), you can create the columns in your database corresponding to your datagrid view.

Suggestion -1-

You bind your "Cars As List(of Car)" to the DataGridView. Now you can run through the objects with reflection and even create the table with this (code untested, database.executeQuery() is just a place holder for your database execution function):

```
database.exeuteQuery("CREATE TABLE car")
for each pi as PropertyInfo in GetType(Car).getProperties()
    database.executeQuery("ALTER TABLE car ADD COLUMN " & pi.name & " TEXT(255)")
next for
for each car as Car in Cars
    Dim insert As String = ""
    Dim values as String = ""
    for each pi as PropertyInfo in car.getType().getProperties()
        if insert <> "" then
            insert &= ", "
            values &= ", "
        end if
        insert &= pi.name
        values &= pi.getValue(car, nothing)
    next for
    database.executeQuery("INSERT INTO car (" & insert & ") VALUES (" & values & ")")
next for
```

Suggestion -2-

You store the name-value pairs in the database. If your grid is "small" (100000 < row*colums) this is fast enough and posses a lot of flexibility without having to change the database structure.

```
For Each row as DataGridViewRow in MyDataGridView.Rows
    For Each col as DataGridViewColumn in MyDataGridView.Columns
        database.executeQuery("INSERT INFO dgvContent( RowId, Name, Value ) VALUES ( " & row.Index & ", '" & col.Name & "', '" & row.Cells(col).Value & "' ")
    Next For
Next For
```

To retrieve and update the data you can use the RowId to get the values of one row back together.

Suggestion -3-

This is a combination of suggestion 2 and 1. You create the DataGridView columns in your Database and have the DataGridView exactly the same way in your database. This is more flexible then Suggestion -1-, since you cannot change the Properties of an object "on the fly", but a lot more hassle then Suggestion -2- since you have to create, remove and organize the table structure. Real statistic analysis are possible with suggestion -3-, but since the table structure is not static, it is very hard to implement. (No Code for this example. Just combine Suggestion 2 code with Suggestion 1 code)

Conclusion

I think there is no best way to save a DataGridView with ANY rows and ANY columns. It all depends on the situation. Sometimes i would use Suggestion -2-, since it is eays to code and the database structure is static. Sometimes i would use Suggestion -3-, since it can handle more data and writing querys against it feels more natural. But here the database structure changes a lot. The changes takes time

Further on the road

In a little bit bigger applications i never fill data directly from the DataGridView to the database. I always use one abstraction layer (model layer, like ORM) between them. I think that has following advantages:
 1. You can use your database routines more flexible for more then just this one DataGridView. (I realy realy hate code duplication in any way.)
 2. You can make changes more easily: If the DataGridView changes, you dont have to think about the database, only your light-weight abstraction layer. If your database changes, you do not have to tough your view.
 3. The data logic is not part of the view, the data logic goes to the model layer.